# A facade root has not been set at upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I upload my laravel 5.8 project on shared hosting. after uploading it shows me given error. can anyone help me?
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/nooralqu/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:236 Stack trace: #0 /home/nooralqu/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(407): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('replaceNamespac...', Array) #1 /home/nooralqu/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(384): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths() #2 /home/nooralqu/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(295): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException)) #3 /home/nooralqu/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(192): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpEx in /home/nooralqu/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 236

Comment: would need more of the error than that, there should be a whole stack trace to see what facade is being accessed that hasn't had a root set

Comment: complete error is given below. kindly help?